# What does 一块牌子，两套人马 mean?

Tags: word

Does that mean a brand name can have two types of production teams? As in the automaking industry, whole work is divided into smaller sections, with different teams doing separately their own assignment?

Comment: Should it be 一套人马两块牌子?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a description of the functioning of an administration system. While '牌子' is the official name of the working unit, '人马' means the staff of the unit. '两套' means double(group) of the working staff, with one group focusing on say daily administration the other on discipline enforcement.

Answer (score 3):

This is a special phase in China Politics.

Since CCP are ruling party in China, lots of stuff are controlled both by party & government. So they are same people & same org but in different names. And sometimes government branch or agency are subject to change (being merged to other branch/agencies or other adjustments), they still keep their original name for convenience or international cooperation.

As example, nuclear related affairs are managed by Ministry of Industry & Information Technology, but MIIT also have a name "National Nuclear Safety Administration".

ref.
https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%80%E4%B8%AA%E6%9C%BA%E6%9E%84%E4%B8%A4%E5%9D%97%E7%89%8C%E5%AD%90

Answer (score 0):

一块牌子，两套人马 - The direct translation is "one agency/command, two teams" which literally means "two teams under one command".

牌子 refers to the 腰牌 used in the ancient law/justice agencies. It was a piece of ID (made of wood or jade) worn on the waist belt for ease of identifying the belonging of a government agent, as each agency has a unique design of its ID (腰牌).